# deleting columns in tflearn producing strange output

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, tflearn

I am using `tflearn` and I am using the following code to load my csv file...

data, labels = load_csv('/home/eric/Documents/Speed Dating Data.csv',
                            target_column=0, categorical_labels=False)

Here is a snippet of my csv file (there are a lot more columns)...

[image]

I want to remove a specific column. For example, let's say I remove column 1 and then print out the data for column 1 to 5...

```
def preprocess(cols_del):
data, labels = load_csv('/home/eric/Documents/Speed Dating Data.csv',
                        target_column=0, categorical_labels=False)

for col_del in sorted(cols_del):
    [data.pop(col_del) for position in data]

for i in range(20):
    print(data[i][0:5])

def main(_):
    delete = [0]
    preprocess(delete)
```

This is the result...

```
['9', '1', '18', '2', '11']
['9', '1', '18', '2', '11']
['9', '1', '18', '2', '11']
['9', '1', '18', '2', '11']
['9', '1', '18', '2', '11']
['9', '1', '18', '2', '11']
['9', '1', '18', '2', '11']
['9', '1', '18', '2', '11']
['9', '1', '18', '2', '11']
['9', '1', '18', '2', '11']
['9', '1', '18', '2', '11']
['10', '1', '20', '2', '11']
['10', '1', '20', '2', '11']
['10', '1', '20', '2', '11']
['10', '1', '20', '2', '11']
['10', '1', '20', '2', '11']
['10', '1', '20', '2', '11']
['10', '1', '20', '2', '11']
['10', '1', '20', '2', '11']
['10', '1', '20', '2', '11']
```

The data is clearly different. What is going on? Are rows being deleted instead of column? How can I delete the entire column completely without altering any other columns?

Also, I know it is kind of a separate question, but if I were to use `n_classes` in my load csv function, how would I do that? Is that the number of column in my CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that the line `[data.pop(col_del) for position in data]` is deleting half your rows, and then you're displaying the first 20 rows of what's left.  (It would delete all the rows, but the call to `pop` is advancing the loop iterator.)

If you don't want certain columns you should pass your `delete` list to the `columns_to_ignore` parameter when you call `load_csv`.  See the function description at [load_csv](http://tflearn.org/data_utils/#load_csv/).  If you need to remove columns from a dataset in memory I think it would be worth your time to learn the basics of the Pandas library; it will make your life much simpler.

You would need `n_classes` if your target labels were categorical, in order to tell `load_csv` how many categories there are.  Since you have `categorical_labels=False`, you shouldn't need it.